# send string parameter with spaces to java function with telerik grid clientTemplate

Tags: java, grid, telerik

I use telerik grid with ajax binding, and i need to send string (with spaces) parameter to java function like:

```
 n.Bound(c => c.Item).ClientTemplate("<button onclick=AddToInvoice('<#=ItemName#>');>Add </button>").Title("");
```

no problem when i send string without space
but when i send with spaces for example "Hello world" i got error unterminated string literal
please any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something instead of space and when your Java function receives the parameter you can parse it and you will be able to put your spaces back.

Comment: can you give exaple how to replace space with someting in my code

Comment: If you use !^! for instance instead of space you can send "First Second" as "First!^!Second" and you can replace the "!^!" at server side with " "

Comment: Thank u Lajos for your replay , and understand ur idea , but i need to know how to replace string inside string param  <#=ItemName#> "onclick=AddToInvoice('<#=ItemName#>');>"

Comment: String foo = "onclick=AddToInvoice('<#=ItemName#>');>"; foo = foo.replace(" ", "!^!"); if you want to do this in Java.